# CodeMirror delete a editor instance

Tags: javascript, editor, instance, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror to do some syntax highlighting in my web. I've created two radio buttons in my html. And my JavaScript code is as follows:

```
if(flag == "C")
    Editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-csrc"
});
else if(flag == "Cpp")
    Editor.off(0);
    Editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-c++src"
});
```

It does complete the function of syntax highlighting, but the problem is when I click the radio button multiple times, it just create as many as I click, and this is annoying. So I am wondering is there any way to delete the previous editor instance before I create a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors created with `fromTextArea` have a `toTextArea` method to remove them. Alternatively, simply create the editor once and use `Editor.setOption("mode", "text/x-csrc")`.

Comment: Yes, toTextArea method is what i want. I have already slove my problem. thanks all Marjin and Bren1818.

Comment: can you please provide fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

cm.getWrapperElement() → Element
Returns the DOM node that represents the editor, and controls its size. Remove this from your tree to delete an editor instance.

See the documentation. http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html